# My kafka docker container cannot connect to my zookeeper docker container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I want to use both `confluent/kafka` and `confluent/zookeeper` and run them on a single Ubuntu server.

I'm using the following configurations:

`docker run -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 --name zookeeper confluent/zookeeper`

`docker run --name kafka -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181 -e KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS=testtopic:1:1 confluent/kafka`

However this results in: Unable to connect to zookeeper:2181

I have other containers that I'd like to connect to, how can I access zookeeper via zookeeper:2181 and kafka via kafka:9092 ?

Comment: Both of these containers are deprecated. Use `confluentinc/kafka` and Zookeeper . Also, please use Docker compose and read this blog https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 - I was using a docker compose, but the images started failing (it worked up until last week), so I've been running the images as per above to help to debug the failing container.  I will try the commands above, with `confluentinc/kafka` and `confluentinc/zookeeper`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. But before we look into it there are two problems in your approach that you need to understand

- `zookeper` host is not reachable when you use `docker run` as each of the containers is running in a different network isolation
- `kafka` may start and try to connect to `zookeeper` but `zookeeper` is not ready yet

#### Solving the network issue

You can do a lot of things to fix things

use `--net=host` to run both on the host network

use `docker network create <name>` and then use `--net=<name>` while launching both the containers

Or you can run your kafka container on the `zookeeper` containers network.

use `--net=container:zookeeper` when launching `kafka` container. This will make sure `zookeeper` host is accessible. This is not recommended as such, until unless you have some strong reason to do so. Because as soon as `zookeeper` container goes down, so will be the network of your `kafka` container. But for the sake of understanding, I have put this option here

#### Solving the startup race issue

Either you can keep a gap between starting `zookeeper` and `kafka`, to make sure that when `kafka` starts `zookeeper` is up and running

Another option is to use `--restart=on-failure` flag with docker run. This will make sure the container is restarted on failure and will try to reconnect to `zookeeper` and hopefully that time `zookeeper` will be up.

Instead of using `docker run` I would always prefer the `docker-compose` to get such linked containers to be run. You can do that by creating a simple `docker-compose.yml` file and then running it with `docker-compsoe up`

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluent/zookeeper
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
  kafka:
    image: confluent/kafka
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS=testtopic:1:1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    restart: on-failure
```

Comment: `docker run -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 --name zookeeper confluent/zookeeper` followed by `docker run --name kafka -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181 -e KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS=testtopic:1:1 --net=container:zookeeper confluent/kafka` did not work.  And showed "Unable to connect to zookeeper:2181"

Comment: Did you do it after a delay?

Comment: Yes, I executed the first command, it showed : "INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181", then waited 2 minutes, checked it was still running, then executed the second command.

Comment: Try with `localhost:2181` then

Comment: Thanks that works! I would like this to work with zookeeper though. So perhaps there is another environment variable for advertised_name with zookeeper.

Comment: Best is to use `docker-compose` instead of just `docker`

Answer (score 4):

I'm running on Mac though, this is working fine. since 'host' networking not working in mac i just create a network called `kafka_net` and put the containers there.

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluent/zookeeper
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
    networks:
      - kafka_net
  kafka:
    image: confluent/kafka
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - kafka_net
    restart: on-failure
networks:
  kafka_net:
    driver: "bridge"
```

To make sure all working:

**Log into the zookeeper container then**

```
zookeeper-shell localhost:2181 => You should see something like 'Welcome to ZooKeeper!' after all the big chunk of text
```

**Log into kafka container then**

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --list # empty list
kafka-topics --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --create --topic first_topic --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1
kafka-topics --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --list # you will see the first_topic
kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic first_topic # type some text and ctrl + c
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --topic first_topic --from-beginning # you will see the stuff you typed first_topic
```

If still giving problems have a look in the official examples. https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/tree/5.2.2-post/examples and still giving issues post it, will give a hand.

Comment: much better answer

Answer (score 1):

Docker start containers in isolated network, called `default bridge` unless you specify network explicitly.

You can succeed in different ways, here are 2 easiest:

1. Put containers into same user-defined bridge network

   ```
   # create net
   docker network create foo
   docker run --network=foo -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 --name zookeeper confluent/zookeeper
   docker run --network=foo --name kafka -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181 -e KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS=testtopic:1:1 confluent/kafka
   ```
2. Expose ports and connect through localhost

   ```
   docker run -p 2181:2181 -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 --name zookeeper confluent/zookeeper
   docker run --name kafka -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=host.docker.internal:2181 -e KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS=testtopic:1:1 confluent/kafka
   ```

Note: in second approach you should use `host.docker.internal` as a host name and expose (publish) port `2181` for first container to make it available on localhost

Comment: I tried the first option, and when running the second line it throws "org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkException: Unable to connect to zookeeper:2181"

Comment: I tried the second option, and I also get Unable to connect to zookeeper:2181

Comment: `KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS` isn't valid for these containers, also, you don't need the docker host DNS name here

Answer (score 0):

```
 docker network create kafka-zookeeper
```

Wait until Network is Created

```
 docker run -it -d --network=kafka-zookeeper --name zookeeper zookeeper
```

Wait until ZooKeeper is up and Running

```
 docker run -it -d --network=kafka-zookeeper --name kafka -e KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181 --restart=on-failure -e ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes -e KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092 -e KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 bitnami/kafka
```

Kafka Should be connecting fine.

These are running in -d detached mode, so you need to go to Docker Desktop to view the logs for each container.