# kafka unable to register brokers in zookeeper when we combine kafka and kafka-rest-proxy image

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I want to install kafka rest proxy along with kafka in a  docker single image. we are using kafka image as base image and want to install kafka-rest-proxy on the top of it. Below mentioned is our Docker-file

`We have taken this as reference while creating this file` https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest-images/blob/master/kafka-rest/Dockerfile.deb8

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.0

ARG PROJECT_VERSION
ARG ARTIFACT_ID

ARG CONFLUENT_VERSION
ARG CONFLUENT_PACKAGES_REPO
ARG CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_LABEL
ARG CONFLUENT_DEB_VERSION
ARG ALLOW_UNSIGNED

LABEL io.confluent.docker.git.repo="confluentinc/kafka-rest-images"

ENV COMPONENT=kafka-rest
ENV KAFKA_REST_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=myzookeeper-zk:2181
ENV KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME=test-kafka

# default listener
EXPOSE 8082

RUN echo "===> Installing ${COMPONENT}..." \
    && apt-get update \
    && echo "===> Adding confluent repository...https://packages.confluent.io/deb/5.5" \
    && if [ "x$ALLOW_UNSIGNED" = "xtrue" ]; then echo "APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated \"true\";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/allow_unauthenticated; else curl -s -L https://packages.confluent.io/deb/5.5/archive.key -o /tmp/archive.key && apt-key add /tmp/archive.key; fi \
    && echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.confluent.io/deb/5.5 stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && sed -i 's;http://archive.debian.org/debian/;http://deb.debian.org/debian/;' /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && cat /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https \
    && apt-get install -y apt-utils \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y confluent-${COMPONENT}=${CONFLUENT_VERSION}${CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_LABEL}-${CONFLUENT_DEB_VERSION} \
    confluent-control-center=${CONFLUENT_VERSION}${CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_LABEL}-${CONFLUENT_DEB_VERSION} \
    confluent-security=${CONFLUENT_VERSION}${CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_LABEL}-${CONFLUENT_DEB_VERSION} \
    && echo "===> clean up ..."  \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && echo "===> Setting up ${COMPONENT} dirs" \
    && chmod -R ag+w /etc/${COMPONENT}


COPY include/etc/confluent/docker /etc/confluent/docker

CMD ["/etc/confluent/docker/run"]
```

---

Image got successfully built

```
docker build . -t my-kafka-rest-custom:3.3.3
Sending build context to Docker daemon  358.4kB
Step 1/21 : FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.1
 ---> 5467234daea9
Step 2/21 : ARG PROJECT_VERSION
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bf90e3020232
Step 3/21 : ARG ARTIFACT_ID
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3306ca86672a
Step 4/21 : ARG CONFLUENT_VERSION
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 09f037fa5954
Step 5/21 : ARG CONFLUENT_PACKAGES_REPO
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6760a594ee94
Step 6/21 : ARG CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_LABEL
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d1321ff49c72
Step 7/21 : ARG CONFLUENT_DEB_VERSION
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2cdb2b914f65
Step 8/21 : ARG ALLOW_UNSIGNED
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8ba2b344ed5e
Step 9/21 : LABEL io.confluent.docker.git.repo="confluentinc/kafka-rest-images"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a07481842889
Step 10/21 : ENV COMPONENT=kafka-rest
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3ac4051385f1
.
.
.
.
.
.

Step 15/21 : ENV KAFKA_REST_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=myzookeeper-zk
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 470e38dda0d1
Step 16/21 : ENV KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME=test-kafka
 ---> Using cache
 ---> faf0fc54ded6
Step 17/21 : EXPOSE 8082
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bd28c9c8e539
Step 18/21 : RUN echo "===> Installing ${COMPONENT}..."     && apt-get update     && echo "===> Adding confluent repository...https://packages.confluent.io/deb/5.5"     && if [ "x$ALLOW_UNSIGNED" = "xtrue" ]; then echo "APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated \"true\";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/allow_unauthenticated; else curl -s -L https://packages.confluent.io/deb/5.5/archive.key -o /tmp/archive.key && apt-key add /tmp/archive.key; fi     && echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.confluent.io/deb/5.5 stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list     && sed -i 's;http://archive.debian.org/debian/;http://deb.debian.org/debian/;' /etc/apt/sources.list     && cat /etc/apt/sources.list     && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https     && apt-get install -y apt-utils     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y confluent-${COMPONENT}=${CONFLUENT_VERSION}${CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_LABEL}-${CONFLUENT_DEB_VERSION}     confluent-control-center=${CONFLUENT_VERSION}${CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_LABEL}-${CONFLUENT_DEB_VERSION}     confluent-security=${CONFLUENT_VERSION}${CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_LABEL}-${CONFLUENT_DEB_VERSION}     && echo "===> clean up ..."      && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/lib/apt/lists/*     && echo "===> Setting up ${COMPONENT} dirs"     && chmod -R ag+w /etc/${COMPONENT}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4d311cc7cf93
Step 19/21 : COPY include/etc/confluent/docker /etc/confluent/docker
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 579bd961c0d8
.
.

Step 21/21 : CMD ["/etc/confluent/docker/run"]
 ---> Running in 4e7051ffde90
Removing intermediate container 4e7051ffde90
 ---> 61376569c763
Successfully built 61376569c763
Successfully tagged my-kafka-rest-custom:3.3.3
```

---

When I am trying to install it using helm charts on Openshift , Image is successfully pulled and container got created but it is getting restarted again and again and after sometime it is crashing. While checking logs we encounter with following errors in logs

```
    main-SendThread(myzookeeper-zk:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /10.130.27.9:45270, server: myzookeeper-zk/10.128.105.218:2181
[main-SendThread(myzookeeper-zk:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server myzookeeper-zk/10.128.105.218:2181, sessionid = 0x20039cfaa970059, negotiated timeout = 40000
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x20039cfaa970059 closed
[main] ERROR io.confluent.admin.utils.cli.KafkaReadyCommand - Error while running kafka-ready.
[main-EventThread] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down for session: 0x20039cfaa970059
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for Kafka to register brokers in Zookeeper. timeout (ms) = 40000
```

Comment: So the kafka broker is not able to connect to zookeeper server on port 2181. Is the port's allowed between these 2 servers ? Please check answers here for similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56496899/my-kafka-docker-container-cannot-connect-to-my-zookeeper-docker-container.

Comment: I have checked connectivity from kafka to zookeeper and I am able to ping zookeeper from kafka                                                                                                                     $ ping myzookeeper-zk
PING myzookeeper-zk.kafka-test.svc.cluster.local (10.128.105.218) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from myzookeeper-zk-1.myzookeeper-zk.kafka-test.svc.cluster.local (10.128.105.218): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.448 ms

Comment: Don't install rest proxy on the broker. Run a separate service

Answer (score 0):

By overwriting the component variable, the broker will no longer start.

The rest proxy needs a broker